# THREE.JS - Vector3.project returns weird result

Tags: javascript, vector, 3d, three.js, 2d

I'm writing a program in THREE.JS and I need to project a Vector3. When I try to project the Vector3 (0,0,0), which should be in the center of the screen in my camera, I get NaN. Other Vector3s that are all visible (though visibility shouldn't make a difference, right?) return stuff like NaN, 0, Infinity, and random numbers between -1 and 0 (usually). Here's some code:

```
camera.position.x=32;
camera.position.y=32;
camera.position.z=32;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
for(var x=0;x<=16;x++)
{
    for(var z=0;z<=16;z++)
    {
        var p=new THREE.Vector3(x,0,z).project(camera);
        alert(p.x+" "+p.y+" "+p.z);
        //HELP!!!
    }
}
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when using a PerspectiveCamera to calculate the projected coordinates of Vector3s without using a Scene or WebGLRenderer.

In my case, I simply had to call `camera.getWorldPosition()`, which updated the cameras world matrix and `point.project(camera)` started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To set the camera position you need to use setters (this changed since `r67`? if I am not mistaken). So like this:

```
camera.position.setX( 32 );
camera.position.setY( 32 );
camera.position.setZ( 32 );
```

or

```
camera.position.set( 32, 32, 32 );
```

Because you didn't use setters the position of your camera is most likely also `(0, 0, 0)`.

It is not possible to project a Vector from itself to itself. A solution to prevent this in the future might be to add a clause that checks equality of camera position with the vector:

```
vector = new THREE.Vector3( x, 0, z );
if( ! camera.position.equals( vector ) ){
    var p = vector.project(camera);
}
```